# Android/Java - Convert double price to String, with a currency parameter given

Tags: java, android, string, formatting, currency

I know it has been asked a lot of times, and I did manage to get a lot of Google & stackoverflow results on this matter, but the one I tried doesn't work and gives an `IllegalArgumentExceptions`.

**How do I convert a `double` price to a `String`, with a `Euro[€]`/`Dollar[$]` currency given?**

This is my code:

```
// Convert Price-Double to String
public static String doubleToPrice(double price, String currency){
    // Create DecimalFormat based on Currency
    // Default (Euro)
    // Use "€##.###,##"
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("€##.###,##");
    // currency parameter given
    if(currency != null && !currency.trim().equals(""))
        // Dollar
        // Use "$##,###.##"
        if(currency.trim().equals("$"))
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("$##,###.##");
    // no currency parameter given: use Config.CURRENCY instead
    else
        // Dollar
        // Use "$##,###.##"
        if(compare(currency, Config.CURRENCY))
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("$##,###.##");

    // Format the string
    String priceString = formatter.format(price);

    // Add a space between the currency and the price value
    priceString = priceString.substring(0, 1) + " " + priceString.substring(1, priceString.length());

    // Replace last two "00" digits for "-"
    if(priceString.endsWith("00")){
        int i = priceString.lastIndexOf("00");
        priceString = new StringBuilder(priceString).replace(i, i+2, "-").toString();
    }

    return priceString;
}
```

When I use the `€` as currency `parameter`, I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException` at `DecimalFormatter formatter = new DecimalFormatter("€##.###,##");`. Does anyone know what is wrong with my `DecimalFormatter prefix`?

I'm also getting an `IllegalArgumentException` when I remove the `€` or `$` from my `Formatter prefix`.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

EDIT 1 (Some examples):

```
doubleToPrice(4.23, "€"); should return "€ 4,23"
doubleToPrice(7.3, "€"); should return "€ 7,30"
doubleToPrice(9, "€"); should return "€ 9,-"
doubleToPrice(12345678.9, "€"); should return "€ 12.345.678,90"
doubleToPrice(0.39, "€"); should return "€ 0,39"
doubleToPrice(0.06, "€"); should return "€ 0,06"

doubleToPrice(4.23, "$"); should return "$ 4.23"
doubleToPrice(7.3, "$"); should return "$ 7.30"
doubleToPrice(9, "$"); should return "$ 9.-"
doubleToPrice(12345678.9, "$"); should return "$ 12,345,678.90"
doubleToPrice(0.39, "$"); should return "$ 0.39"
doubleToPrice(0.06, "$"); should return "$ 0.06"
```

**EDIT 2 / Solution:**

Accepted Hirak's answer, since he covered most of the things I wanted after his edit. Still, here is the finished code with the "hacks" for converting `00` to `-`.

```
// Convert Price-Double to String
public static String doubleToPrice(double price, char currency){
    // Define currency to be used
    char curr = Config.CURRENCY;
    if(currency == '€' || currency == '$')
        curr = currency;

    // Format the string using a DecimalFormat
    Locale locale = new Locale("de", "DE");
    if(curr == '$')
        locale = new Locale("en", "US");
    DecimalFormatSymbols sym = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
    sym.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    if(curr == '$')
        sym.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    formatter.applyPattern(curr + "##,##0.00");
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);

    String returnString = formatter.format(price);

    // Replace "00" after the comma with "-"
    if(returnString.endsWith("00")){
        int i = returnString.lastIndexOf("00");
        returnString = new StringBuilder(returnString).replace(i, i+2, "-").toString();
    }

    // Add space between currency-symbol and price
    returnString = returnString.substring(0, 1) + " " + returnString.substring(1, returnString.length());

    Log.i("PRICE FORMATTING", "double that goes in [" + price + "]; string that comes out [" + returnString + "]");

    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make a resource like "<string name="price">%1$s %2$s</string> in strings.xml" and then in your method: public static String doubleToPrice(double price, String currency){ return getResource().getString(R.string.price, price+"", currency) }

Comment: @EmilPana I used to do so. But seperator is the matter here..

Comment: Sorry, in place of price+"", put "new DecimalFormat("##,###.##").format(price)"

Comment: Create "<string name="price">$%1$,.2f</string> in strings.xml" 
and write the method as EmilPana told,

 public static String doubleToPrice(double price, String currency){ return String.format(getResource().getString(R.string.price), currency); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? (note that, even though I have put DOT as decimal separator, in the output, you will get COMMA as decimal deparator, because Java decides at runtime based on the locale.)

```
   static String doubleToPrice(double dbl,char currency) {
    Locale locale =null;
    if(currency=='€') {
    locale  = new Locale("fr", "FR");
    }else {
        locale  = new Locale("en", "EN");
    }//Add locales as per need.
    DecimalFormatSymbols sym = new DecimalFormatSymbols(locale);
    sym.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)
            NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    decimalFormat.applyPattern(currency+"##,###.00");
    decimalFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);
    return decimalFormat.format(dbl);
}
```

Comment: Your answer looks a bit incomplete. For instance, it doesn't format 7.3 to 7,30; and it also doesn't make a difference between fr_FR and en_US format based on the given currency parameter. I've made an edit to my main post to make it more clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: I have made changes to my code. This should meet all your need, but "//should return "9,-" currently I cannot think of a way to implement this pattern, unless we do some custom hacks...

Comment: Thanks, after some changes and including some custom hacks for converting ending `00` to `-`, you answer did the trick. Added my complete solution code to the main post and accepted your answer as the correct one.